# Retain selected option after form submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code that get some options from database using php and mysql

```html
<select class="form-control" id="Type" name="Type">
  <option></option>
  <?php
      $TypeQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Details";
      $TypeQueryExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $TypeQuery);
      while($TypeQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_array($TypeQueryExecute)){
           $Type = $TypeQueryRow['Type'];
           echo "<option value='{$Type}'>{$Type}</option>";
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

I want to retain the dropdown list selection after form submission. I am using `php` `$_POST['']` method for form submission. I tried the following way. But it is not working.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="Type" name="Type">
  <option></option>
  <?php
     $TypeQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM oaDetails";
     $TypeQueryExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $TypeQuery);
        while($TypeQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_array($TypeQueryExecute)){
        $Type = $TypeQueryRow['Type'];
   ?>
    <option <?php if ($_POST['Type']==$Type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >
      <?php echo $Type; ?>
    </option>

    <?php
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1**

I tried the following way. Now it is not showing any options. Instead some errors

`<option value=<?php echo $_POST['Type']; ?>  <?php if ($_POST['Type'] == $Type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> ><?php echo $_POST['Type']; ?></option>`

**Edit 2**

I tried following way and this time it is retaining the values. But only thing is if I select an option with spacing in between and click submit, the value is not retaining and just go to default blank. You can see what I mean by option with spacing as below

[image]

Options with no space as below retaining and working well as per my need

[image]

Comment: just check the values of `$_POST['Type']` & `$Type`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Your code is correct just echo `$_POST['Type']` and check

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Its not working also

Comment: `<option value=<?php echo $Type; ?>  <?php if (isset($_POST['Type']) && $_POST['Type'] == $Type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> ><?php echo $Type; ?></option>` try this

Comment: Do you submit form on same page?

Comment: @Omi Now it is showing all the options when page load. But once I submit, all the options changing to `Undefined variable: Type`

Comment: @AnkurMishra Yes. same page

Comment: just check the name you have used to take type from row i think it should be `$Type`, as you have declared in while

Comment: @Omi It is working after I corrected the variable as per your instruction. But now the strange thing is, the moment options have a space in between, its not working. But if not space then its fine. Eg; if one of the options is XXX 1, then it is not retaining. But if choose an option XXX1 then it is retaining. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I didnt get what you are saying moment and all that could you please modify your question

Comment: @Omi Updated. Now you can see what i meant by `XXX 1` and `XXX1`

Comment: this type is come from database right? why there is space in between xxx1 or do you have two value in db xxx1 and xxx 1

Comment: @Omi I have two values in database. One is xxx1 and another one is xxx 1

Comment: then also your select should have two values, so when you select xxx1 it will show xxx1 selected and same for xxx 1 of you select xxx 1 from dropdown

Comment: @Omi It is correctly showing in selection. My problem was once I select lets say `xxx 1` and click the button, selection just go default blank. But if I choose `xxx1`, there is no such issue. Anyway I got it right from another member. It was caused by the `""` are not placed for the `HTML` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes in your output HTML, that's why spaces in the value throw you out. It should be
`<option value="<?php echo $_POST['Type']; ?>"  <?php if ($_POST['Type'] == $Type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> ><?php echo $_POST['Type']; ?></option>`

Comment: With some fine tuning, I got it right. But the main cause was due to the `""` not placed for HTML tags as you pointed out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to clarify, I got it right this way. 

`<option value="<?php echo $Type; ?>"  <?php if (isset($_POST['Type']) && $_POST['Type'] == $Type) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> ><?php echo $Type; ?></option>`